# Code review, C++, Anagram method

Tags: c++, big-o, review, anagram

I'm doing some practice questions from the book "Cracking the coding interview" and wanted to get some people to review my code for bugs and optimizations. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Question: Write a method to decide if two strings are anagrams or not.

```
/*
Time complexity: O(n^2)
Space complexity: O(n)
*/
bool IsAnagram(std::string str1, std::string str2)
{
    if(str1.length() != str2.length())
        return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < str1.length();i++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        int j = 0;
        while(!found && j < str2.length())
        {
            if(str1[i] == str2[j])
            {
                found = true;
                str2[j] = NULL;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if(!found)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: A better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You can get `O(n lg n)` time if you sort both strings...

Comment: @Cameron Has the right idea. Sort both strings, then compare character by character. If they match all the way through, they're anagrams.

Comment: I suspect it is also possible to specialize your sorting algorithm to also check for the anagram, to eliminate the need for the last check. This wouldn't decrease your overall time complexity, however.

Comment: @JoshKelley Thanks I didnt even know it existed. I'll  be sure to post on there in the future.
Cameron I did think about that but wasn't sure if the the time to sort both would be worth it.

Comment: @TehanFrago - Doing an `O(n lg n)` operation is almost always worth it if it lets you avoid an `O(n^2)` operation; that's what big O notation _means_.  (I say "almost always" because there may be specialized instances where complicating factors, like constant time overhead, are more important.)

Comment: @Cameron, no need to sort, you can do it in linear time.

Answer (score 5):

This is more efficient generally

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool IsAnagram(std::string& str1, std::string& str2)
{
  if(str1.length() != str2.length())
    return false;

  std::sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());
  std::sort(str2.begin(), str2.end());

  return str1.compare(str2) == 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string an1("army");
  std::string an2("mary");
  if(IsAnagram(an1, an2)) 
    std::cout << "Hooray!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

For those who dislike the mutating strings then maybe this is a better option. Could either remove reference to parameters 1 and 2 or make a copy inside function as here.  This way, parameters can be const.

```
bool IsAnagram2(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2)
{
   if(str1.length() != str2.length())
      return false;

   std::string cpy1(str1), cpy2(str2);

   std::sort(cpy1.begin(), cpy1.end());
   std::sort(cpy2.begin(), cpy2.end());

   return cpy1.compare(cpy2) == 0;
}
```

Comment: This modifies the strings you pass to the function, though. That might not be expected!

Comment: It's better not to trash your arguments... so I would take those &'s off and let IsAnagram work from a local copy.  But still:  this is a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 3):

`O(n)` algorithm.  Instead of sorting (which is `O(n lg n)`), count up the character occurrences in s1 and compare it to the character occurrences in s2.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

bool IsAnagram(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
  if (s1.size() != s2.size()) {
    return false;
  }
  int count[std::numeric_limits<char>::max() + (std::size_t)1] = {};
  for (auto c : s1) {
    count[c]++;
  }
  for (auto c : s2) {
    if (!count[c]) {
      return false;
    }
    count[c]--;
  }
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::cout << IsAnagram(argv[1], argv[2]) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, very nice. Shouldn't that technically be `..::max() + (std::size_t)1` though? (On the other hand, I guess all of these answers assume ASCII anyway -- anagrams of Unicode encoded into byte strings are much less fun.) And it might be a good idea to allocate it off the stack, in case there's a platform with a wide `char` and a small stack.

Comment: @Cameron - I fixed the `+1` issue. Thanks. I realize stack allocation can be a problem on some platforms, but I think I still prefer it for a typical or default algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There is already standard algorithm `std::is_permutation` that allows to perform the task simply

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


int main() 
{

    std::string s( "aab" );
    std::string t( "aba" );

    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
              << ( s.size() == t.size() && 
                   std::is_permutation( s.begin(), s.end(), t.begin() ) )
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
true
```

So all ypu need is to see how the algorithm is realized.:)

If you want a separate function then it will look like

```
bool IsAnagram( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
    return s1.size() == s2.size() &&
           std::is_permutation( s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin() );
}
```

To use `std::sort` is not a good approach because original strings will be changed or you have to pass them to the function by value.

Comment: Good thinking but you should mention it needs a reasonably modern compiler - is_permutation is C++11

Comment: Using the standard library is nice, but note that is_permutation may be up to O(n^2). A custom algorithm can be faster.

Comment: @Josh Kelley A custom algorithm can be faster only in a particular case. Otherwise it would be implemented in std::is_permutation.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - This is a particular case :-). std::strings are random access containers with small, cheap-to-copy members, so sorting (`O(n lg n)`) or counting occurrences (`O(n)`) becomes practical.  If performance is important, I'm more comfortable explicitly coding an algorithm than trusting the standard library to optimize for this case.